# How to convert between iso and cso?

Tags: iso

Is there any way to convert between cso files and iso? I wanted to convert my cso files to iso for playing games on my PSP.

Comment: I have modified the command , two packages you have to install. look at comment or update area.

Comment: worked for you ?

Answer (score 7):

Ciso, small tool, doesn't have too many features but it get the job done (at least that's what they advise:

```
sudo apt-get install ciso
```

> Tool to convert Sony PSP iso to ciso

To convert to ISO:

```
ciso 0 infile.cso outfile.iso
```

To convert to CSO:

```
ciso X infile.iso outfile.cso
```

(X is compression level between 1 and 9).

Comment: how to use ciso to convert iso files?

Comment: dinse@dinse-G41T-M7:~$ ciso 0 ~/desktop/God-of-War.cso ~/desktop/God-of-War.isoCompressed ISO9660 converter Ver.1.01 by BOOSTER
Can't open /home/dinse/desktop/God-of-War.cso
dinse@dinse-G41T-M7:~$ ciso 0 /desktop/God-of-War.cso /desktop/God-of-War.iso
Compressed ISO9660 converter Ver.1.01 by BOOSTER

Answer (score 0):

One more tool named as PSPShrink.

To install open your terminal and paste these lines

```
wget http://lgallardo.com/wp-content/uploads/files/psp/linux/pspshrink-1.1.1.tar.gz
tar xvf pspshrink-1.1.1.tar.gz
cd pspshrink-1.1.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

after installing it , just type as

```
pspshrinkui
```

to launch it.

**Update**: For that error install\

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-dev libglibmm-2.4-dev
```

For more tools and Information you can visit [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PSP)

Comment: configure: error:  +Could not find gtkmm-2.4. Please update PKG_CONFIG_PATH to point at location of gtkmm pkgconfig files directory.-this message is shown when i type ./configure

Comment: @DinseDas try with ` sudo apt-get install build-essential` then try again .

Comment: i tried but it did'nt work

Comment: @DinseDas please this too sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-dev libglibmm-2.4-dev